# STAF fails to run

Tags: staf

I am trying to ping STAF using local host

Command is

```
STAF local ping ping
```

it shows the below error

> Error registering with STAF, RC:21

I have already executed `startSTAFProc.sh` to start `STAF`
it is showing output

> /Library/staf/startSTAFProc.sh ; 
>  exit; 
>  logout [Process completed]

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by setting Host name using command scutil --set HostName name

Then restarted machine and started "startSTAFProc.sh" from terminal